# PropertyReferenceException: No property 'project' found for type 'Project' when Sort by project_id

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In My SpringBoot/JPA (Postgres) project,

I have a table for Projects defined as :

```
create table projects(
 project_id int primary key,
 name varchar(255),
 description text
);
```

In my Controller I have a method for getting the list of Projects:

```
@GetMapping("/list")
@ResponseBody
public Page<Project> list(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails currentUserDetails) {
    int page = 0;
    int size = 100;
    Sort sort = Sort.by("name").ascending();
    PageRequest p = PageRequest.of(page, size, sort);

    return projectService.list(p);
}
```

This all works fine.
The problem comes when I change this code to Sort by the `project_id` column:

```
Sort sort = Sort.by("project_id").ascending();
```

Now I get the following exception at Runtime:

> 2024-01-01T14:34:04,424 ERROR [http-nio-8081-exec-6] o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'project' found for type 'Project'] with root cause
> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'project' found for type 'Project'
> at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.(PropertyPath.java:90)

my Project entity class is as simple as it gets:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Projects")
public class Project {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "ProjectSeq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ProjectSeq", sequenceName = "PROJECTS_PROJECT_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
Integer project_id;
String name;

public Integer getProject_id() {
    return project_id;
}

public void setProject_id(Integer project_id) {
    this.project_id = project_id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

String description;
}
```

Have I stumbled into a reserved-word situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is due to the fact that underscore is interpreted as a delimiter while building the PropertyPath instance. In that moment your `project_id` will be split to `project` + `id`.

To fix it you can change the entity class to use `camelCase` properties. Like this:

```java
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    Integer projectId;
    public Integer getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }
    public void setProjectId(Integer projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }
```

Using the `@Column` annotation you will get the database column name unchanged but the Java name will in `camelCase` - which is recommended for properties.

Answer (score 1):

Underscore is treated as a reserved character as mentioned in [the Spring Data JPA Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/query-methods-details.html#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions):

> Because we treat the underscore character as a reserved character, we
> strongly advise following standard Java naming conventions (that is,
> not using underscores in property names but using camel case instead).

You should change the `project_id` property to `projectId`. It doesn't require any changes on the database since the conversion from camel case to snake case is done by default.